Why is "lvdisplay" command not working in Virtual Box?
Both are newly installed from same ISO, why VMware working with the command of lvdisplay but Virtual box couldn't (able to run but show nothing)?
I tried sudo /sbin/lvm lvdisplay in Virtual box but same result) any hints I can showing properly result in virtual box?
The image downloaded directly from Oracle.

I don't know you have given us enough information about your enviroment to go on.   Are you using the same image in both VMWare and VirtualBox? Are they running the same kernel?  Does "pvdisplay" produce any output?
